# Create, Publish and Subscribe API using manual configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am able to Create, Publish and Subscribe API using WSO2 API Manager web console. Is there a way to do this manually with xml configuration or by any other way?

Answer (score 0):

For creating and publishing an API you need to use the Publisher. For subscribing to an API, you need to do this via the store. Is this what you have been trying to do?

Pls refer the [Quick Start Guide](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Quick+Start+Guide) for details and let us know if you run into any problems.

Cheers,
Gillian

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to add and publish an API through REST API using curl. Is REST API available for subscribing the published API?